# How to achieve same look/design in any aspect ratio?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm having a problem displaying the elements, in 1920x1080 resolution it looks great but in other ratio such as 1366x768 it became bloated. My goal is to have same look in different aspect ratio.

This is the display design in 1920x1080 resolution
[image]

This is the display design in 1366x768 resolution
[image]

P.S: I didn't use the font of vuetify, because in my previous project when I use vuetify fonts the font-size is not resizing

Answer (score 0):

Add Breakpoints on every screen sizes that will determine the font size and other elements you want to be responsive on a screen

Ex:

```
 carouselHeight() {
  const x = this.$vuetify.breakpoint.name;
  //console.log(x)
  switch (x) {
    case "xl":
      return "800";
    case "lg":
      return "300";
    case "md":
      return "340";
    case "sm":
      return "230";
    case "xs":
      return "150";
    default:
      return "150";
  }
```